# Get rows inserted during time range in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

In BiQuery Legacy SQL it's possible to get rows inserted
during a time range.

```sql
#legacySQL
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [PROJECT_ID:DATASET.TABLE@time1-time2]
```

With standard SQL you can do point-in-time query like this

```sql
SELECT *
FROM t
  FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF '2017-01-01 10:00:00-07:00';
```

But I don't find a way to query for the time range as in Legacy SQL.